# Loop through all Signals in the measurement configuration in CANape software and pick only those with same name pattern

Tags: c#, canape

I want to write a code that loops through all signals in the Canape software, look only for signals with similar name pattern and return the signal value. 
There are many signals, but I only look for signals which follow similar pattern. I mean only signals naming: drivingSignal_01, drivingSignal_02, drivingSignal_03…

Does anyone have function programming experience in Canape? Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Is this related to what Wikipedia describes in [CANape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CANape)?

Comment: yes exactly. Relates to programming in CANape software

Comment: Given that there is no [tag:canape] tag yet, I fear you may be the first to ask about it.  You could probably search SO for 'canape' and there will probably only be a few places where the word turns up in a context where it refers to food (and hence no, or very few, Q&A where it refers to the software you’re using).  I’ll add a tag later with an x-ref to the web site. But it probably means there aren’t many people here who can help. You should probably try to find other places to ask about it.

Comment: I've created the tag [tag:canape] and added the tag to a few (7 or so) questions that are unequivocally about CANape.  The SO search I used was '`canape is:q -[canape]`'.  There are a number of questions where the occurrence of 'canape' is coincidental (food related).  There's one (about converting CSV files) which might be CANape — I've not retagged it.  I'm not sure about the relevance of the C# or CASL tags; I don't have the expertise to make the call on those.

Answer (score 0):

This would best be done using the scripting language within CANape. The SignalValueIterator could be used to perform this task. The help on SignalValueIterator has some good examples that you could pull from.

If you would like more details on this I would email Vector at support@us.vector.com